# Retrieving bound data from a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, eval

I have a Gridview connected to a SQL datasource displaying data, and what I hope to do is retrieve data associated with a selected row through a button and Eval.

Somthing like,

```
<asp:LinkButton runat=server OnClientClick="RetrieveInfo" Text="Send" />
```

But I can't call Eval from code, and I don't know how to get the DataKey either.

I've been scouring the internet, but haven't found anything nice. Can anyone help me? Would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
DataKeyNames="ScheduleID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Colums>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date">
           <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date")%>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="starttime">
           <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("starttime")%>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat=server OnClientClick="RetrieveInfo" Text="Send" />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Colums>
</asp:GridView>
```

It's skimmed, but that's basically it.

Comment: The question is little confusing. Can you please provide your HTML markup for the grid and link button? My doubt is where is the link button. Is it inside grid view or outside gridview?

Comment: Thanks you for your interest! I uploaded some more details. And yes the button is inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May this help

Edit your gridview html `<Colums>`  to `</Columns>`

```
<asp:LinkButton runat=server OnClientClick="RetrieveInfo"   CommandName="Update"  Text="Send" />
```

**Gridview Html**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="50%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" >
   <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date">
           <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date")%>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="starttime">
           <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbltime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("starttime","{0:dd MMM yyyy}") %>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="sendvalue" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" OnClientClick="RetrieveInfo" Text="Send" />
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           bindGridview();
       }

   protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "sendvalue")
            {
                int getrow = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                Label lbldate = (Label)GridView1.Rows[getrow].FindControl("lbldate");
                Label lbltime = (Label)GridView1.Rows[getrow].FindControl("lbltime");
                string getDate = lbldate.Text;
                string getStartTime = lbltime.Text;
               //here you retrieve all the value of select row and do your logic for link butn
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                bindGridview();
            }
    }

    public void bindGridview()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("select Date,startTime from yourtable", con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dap.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: @Ravi: thanks for observation, check now updated one with GridView markup

Answer (score 0):

From your code i feel that you need those values to be retreived in the Javascript function call on Button OnClientClick event.You can set the values in Javascript Function for onclick event of the button at the RowDataBound Event of the GridView,and can easily write javascript function to get those values...

**CodeBehind:-**

```
void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {

   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
    Label Label1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1Id");                    
    Label Label2= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label2Id");
    Label Label3= (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label3Id");
    LinkButton lnkBtn= (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkId");
    lnkBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick","RetrieveInfo('"+Label1.Text+"','"+Label2.Text+"','"+Label3.Text+"')");
   }

  }
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
 function RetrieveInfo(Label1Value,Label2Value,Label3Value)
{
   Write your Logic..
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your grid view as follows. Add row databaound and row command functions. 
Row command function will be called when you will click the link button.

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ScheduleID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    OnRowDataBound = "GridView1_OnRowDataBound" 
    onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" >
        <Colums>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date">
               <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date")%>' />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="starttime">
               <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("starttime")%>' />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbBind" runat=server OnClientClick="RetrieveInfo" Text="Send" />
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Colums>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind .cs :**

```
protected void  GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e )
  {
     try
       { if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
           {
             DataRowView drEachRow = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            // Get all controls present in the row.
            LinkButton lbBind= (LinkButton )e.Row.FindControl("lbBind");
            // Add row index as command argument.
            lbBind.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
            }
         }
           catch(Exception objExp)
              {
                 // handle exception
              }
            }

 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
      try
       {   // Check if the command is generated by a button only.
         if (e.CommandSource.GetType().Equals(new LinkButton().GetType()))
         {
             int index;          // Store the index of the current row.
             // Get it from CommandArgument
             int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument), out index);
            // One exacmple of how to get one control in the same row.
           Label lblpid = (Label)gvFinalReview.Rows[index].FindControl("lblplanid");
          // You can get other controls similarly.
         }
       }
        catch(Exception objExp)
         {
            // handle exception
          }
    }
```